# PHPUnit failing if run from different directory

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have my namespaced webapp in a folder named 'library'. If I'm in the directory and run `phpunit` the tests run just fine. However, if I go out of the directory and run `phpunit library/` PHPUnit complains that it can't find the class that I'm calling using the `use` statement.

Here is my phpunit.xml which lives in the 'library' directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="./tests/testsBootstrap.php"
        >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="JTW Framework Test Suite">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>./tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./tests/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

And here is the test that's using the class (shortened):

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Assets;

use Jtw\Assets\Reader;

class ReaderTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testYamlReader()
    {
        $yamlFile = __DIR__ . '/assets/reader.yml';
        $yamlArray = Reader::read($yamlFile);

        $this->assertTrue(is_array($yamlArray));
        $this->assertEquals(2, count($yamlArray));
        $this->assertTrue(in_array('baz', $yamlArray));
        $this->assertTrue(is_array($yamlArray['test']));
        $this->assertEquals('baz', $yamlArray['qux']);
    }
}
```

And my 'testsBootstrap.php' file is bootstrapping WordPress and calling composer's autoload file.

Any ideas as to why the tests would run fine from within the 'library' directory but not from outside it, but pointing to it?

If you want to see the full setup it's on my [GitHub account](https://github.com/jtwebb/jtw-framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from here:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="./tests/testsBootstrap.php"
        >
```

Your tests need to have the bootstrap run in order to run.  When you are not in your `library` directory, PHPUnit is not running the bootstrap and so the tests are not set up properly and fail.

Running the tests from the directory results in PHPUnit running the bootstrap for you.

To get them to run properly you can use `--bootstrap` option.

```
phpunit --bootstrap <path to library>/tests/testBootstrap.php <tests you want to run>
```

Comment: That was exactly it. But I'm curious as to why it won't read my phpunit.xml in the folder I tell it to run the tests in; or at least it won't load the bootstrap.

Comment: Because you can tell phpunit to run any particular files or any subdirectory, so it looks in the current location for a phpunit.xml file.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: instead of specifying bootstrap file only, You can specify PHPUnit configuration file to use `phpunit -c /path/to/phpunit.xml <test to run>`